# Is there way to log only administrative commands/queries on mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, logging

I know, how to enable the general log in MySQL - which logs all the queries from client and the one ran in command prompt.

But, 
I want to log only those commands/queries which are ran in MySQL command prompt (queries which are executed manually on the server) is this achievable by configuration?

Any suggestion/help would be much appreciated. Thanks

version      :-               5.1.71
version_compile_machine :-  x86_64
version_compile_os    :-    redhat-linux-gnu

Comment: MySQL Options for this are limited. You should try some Mysql-Proxy, sitting between your application and the server and see if it has any Options for this. For example "MySQL Router" or "Proxy SQL". If you use google, you'll also find very lightwight proxys, which are just kind of an interceptor.

Comment: @dognose thanks for comment. Looks like MySQL Audit Plugin will also not help me here, as it logs all the statements (including those fired from client).. I will check through for proxies if any. Thanks for suggestion